# php cli & expression engine

Tags: assets, file-uploads, hosting

i just installed EE 2.8.0 on a server running php cli. It seems that this is causing issues with creating new templates & uploading files in general.

Hosting provider is not willing to make any changes.
Any ideas?

Comment: In what way is the CLI causing issues with templates? It seems unlikely that is the cause of your problems.

Comment: i can not create/upload files due to file permission issues. Only via ftp. Is there anything i can change through ee to bypass this?

Comment: Unless I'm very much mistaken this has nothing at all to do with PHP's CLI. You can change folder/file permissions as necessary via FTP. If you have any kind of Shell access you can also do it with that.

Comment: Is there a way to handle ftp connection via EE control panel or any setting in the config file?

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand what you are asking. Why would you want, or need, to control an FTP connection via the site's control panel? I think you need to rethink your question and explain exactly what you are trying to do because I think you're going about it in the wrong way.

Comment: If you are simply unable to have EE create/save templates because of file permissions then just set the file permissions for your templates directory via FTP. There is no need to make this manageable from the Controlpanel - in fact it could present a security issue. You could also just have EE use the database for templates so there is no need for it to save anything to disk.

Comment: I could work via ftp but as soon as i need to create a new template i will not be able to do so through cp. db is not a bad solution though.

Comment: If you set the permissions on the template folder then EE/you will be able to create the files.

Answer (score 1):

This is a permissions problem unrelated to the original question as it was asked.

The solution is to set the read/write permissions for the template directory via FTP (or shell access) which will allow EE to create template files as required.

Comment: although i know this is usually the solution not this time.